# How to determine height of the toolbar in UINavigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uikit

I have a view with a toolbar presented by a UINavigationController.

When I am handling UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, I'm scrolling the entire screen upwards by the height of the keyboard.
The thing is when the keyboard is shown, the bottom toolbar is not, so I need to scroll the screen upwards by only (keyboard.height - toolbar.height).

But how to get the height of the toolbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You just should check the toolbar frame.

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.size.height
```

Of course, it only works if you have a navigation controller...

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the similar solution, but I faced with a problem on a devices like iPhone X, XS and future models. For example, on the iPhone XS height will be 49, but it's not the correct height. After some research I figured out another solution to detect the toolbar height:

Objective-C:

```
CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
CGFloat toolbarTop = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y
CGFloat originalHeight = screenHeight - toolbarTop
```

Swift 5:

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
let toolbarTop = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame.origin.y
let originalHeight = screenHeight - toolbarTop
```

This will show you another number. For example on XS it's 83